# Bootstrap stack 2 columns vertically

Tags: bootstrap-5

I've read the documentation for hours and checked all demos and also searched SO but I can't figure out how to achieve the below layout:

[image]

This is what I've done and the output result looks like what I need but I'm not sure it is the correct way or not:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="w-75 rounded bg-dark">
      <p>
        This is a sample
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="w-25">
      <div class="col rounded bg-dark">
        <p>
        This is a sample
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col rounded bg-dark">
        <p>
        This is a sample
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ezt5fyL1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to nest the grid...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9 rounded bg-dark">
            <p> This is a sample </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="row gy-1 gx-1">
                <div class="col-12 rounded bg-dark">
                    <p> This is a sample </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 rounded bg-dark">
                    <p> This is a sample </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[codeply](https://codeply.com/p/iqsxHCvIDH)

Comment: Juts one more question. How to give the three columns a fixed height regardless of length of the text?